# What does this character mean? (Screenshot)

Tags: characters

this is a very quick question as I do not know any chinese at all, but what does this character mean? I've tried websites that recognize according to handwriting, but it just won't. I tried many times, but I think it may be the font or just my bad handwriting. It just has this one character and that's it, thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: It means empty. （空）

Comment: OP has shown homework (*I've tried websites that recognize according to handwriting, but it just won't. I tried many times, but I think it may be the font or just my bad handwriting.*) - there’s no need to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

The strokes in the upper half of the character looks more like Japanese to me. I think it is 空 (sora), which means sky in Japanese. The meaning of this character is basically the same in Chinese and in Japanese though. So it can also mean nothingness or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s just another way of writing 空 as in 空气 or 空天 or 你有没有空时间呢。

Comment: 你有没有空时间呢 is a wrong sentence.

Comment: @rambler That’s interesting. My wife, who is Chinese and has lived in China her entire life says it is a correct sentence.

Comment: Apparently, "空时间" is not a valid word.

Comment: @rambler it means free time. And it is correct.

Comment: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/33178/why-is-%E7%A9%BA%E6%97%B6%E9%97%B4-not-a-valid-phrase-in-chinese