# Is "空时间" a valid phrase in chinese? If not, why not?

Tags: word-choice, phrase, idioms

For example, "你有没有空时间呢"?
In my intuition, 空时间 is most likely a physics terminology (though it isn't).

Comment: The context is in scheduling. 你的日程有没有空。This has been elaborated to general conversation by many. I did a double take at the suggestion I was incorrect and asked friends if I’d been using it incorrectly for the decade or so I spent in China and nobody so far has said it is incorrect. That said, like in English or any language for that matter, it’s possible incorrect usages are mainstream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

你有没有空时间呢 doesn't sound right. Try these variants:

> 你有没有空?
>
> 你有没有时间?
>
> 你有没有空闲的时间？
>
> 你有没有空闲的时候?

Comment: Can you explain why not a valid word ?

Comment: @rambler Chinese usually don't use 3-character words, there is 空间(space), 时间(time), but no 空时间, in that case you need to use 空闲时间, two 2-character words, or similar forms.

Comment: @Jacob, I said it's a phrase, such as 空教室, 空瓶子

Comment: @rambler, It is definitely a phrase, 教室 is built by a verb(acting like an adjective) + noun, 瓶 is just a single noun(子 is meaningless), but 时间 is combined by two concepts together.  The word-building are different.

Comment: @Jacob , OK what I want to ask is *"Can you explain why not a valid phrase?"* "教室" is a 名词. You can't segment is anymore. Such as "老婆饼", it has its own meaning.

Comment: You know sometimes I can't persuade others if I just say xxx doesn't sound right. The purpose I ask this question is to persuade others.

Comment: @rambler I think 空, when read as kong1, is used as an adjective. 空瓶子 and 空教室 could make sense because 瓶子 and 教室 can be literally filled by something tangible. 时间 isn't a container but is an abstract concept. It can not be filled, so 空时间 makes no sense.

Comment: so how about kong4 , we can only judge it by our experience ?

Comment: @rambler when read as kong4, it's taken as a verb. we should add some complement to make it clear e.g. 空出时间做某事. 空, as a verb, usually takes a specific interval such as 一小时，一天，两段. So, you can say 空一小时，然后再吃药.

Comment: 你有空吗?here kong4 is noun。and 空缺 is also kong 4 noun.

Comment: @rambler yeah, it can be a noun as well.

Comment: @rambler Forget it. I won't answer anymore,only wastes my time. Recently, I have found this isn't interesting. I've use this language for roughly 3 decades, read a wide range texts, ancient classical, modern classical,  modern, poem, prose, formal, informal, colloquial, dialect, though my major is not Chinese, But I do read some texts about the grammar just for hobby. I only post explanations that is proved to be true. But it is not me to learning, if you don't believe my idea, I won't take my time to prove myself. It's you to study Chinese grammar, not me. Hope you can find what you need.

Comment: @Jacob, see comment in this answer, you will understand my situation. I also read  billions of chars. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/33176/20986

Comment: It is not right that Chinese does not use three-characters words, all are custom, there are not fixed rules. Some words are not often heard, so sounds strange. For example, you can say 空闲时间 or 闲时间 but not 空时间, you can say 空瓶子 but not 满瓶子, you may speak 空闲的桌子 or 闲置的桌子 but not 闲桌子. So, there are NOT general RULES!!!

Answer (score 0):

Best Chinese dictionary ever. I’ve been using it since 2010 and it just rocks. And that’s besides general experience over a decade.

[image: screenshot]

So as you can see. It is not limited to discussions of physics. Thanks for the upvotes!